# Firebase Init on the second time only create 2 files

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions

So I am going to use cloud function, therefore I use `firebase init` in a folder, and it works wonder (node_module is created, index.js is also created)

The problem is on the second `firebase init` onward. The initialization only produces 2 files, which is `.firebaserc` and `firebase.json`, with no error whatsoever.

What should I do to create index.js, and other things such as `node_modules` folder after initialization?

PS. I'm a new guy in the npm-nodejs-javascript world, so, I'm not familiar with how node or npm works.
PSS. I already make sure that my firebase-tools version is uptodate (3.9.2)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I didn't select the "functions" option. You actually need to hit spacebar before hitting enter. Otherwise it won't be selected. Silly.